# C# How to write on files with custom name according to string content?

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to learn some C# here. My goal is to create and write on multiple custom files which name varies based on a part of the string to be written. Below some examples:

Let's say strings to be written are basically rows of a `csv` file:

```
2019-10-28 16:14:14;;15.5;0;;3;false;false;0;111;123;;;10;false;1;2.5;;;;0;
2019-10-28 16:13:11;;18;0;;1;false;false;222;333;123;;;10;false;1;1;;;;0;G
2019-10-29 16:13:11;;18;0;;3;false;false;true;
```

As you may notice, first field of each string is a date, and that's and that is the key field to choose the name of the file to write to.

First two fields have same date, so both strings will be printed on a single file, the third one in a second file since it has different date.

Expected Result:

First File:

```
2019-10-28 16:14:14;;15.5;0;;3;false;false;0;111;123;;;10;false;1;2.5;;;;0;
2019-10-28 16:13:11;;18;0;;1;false;false;222;333;123;;;10;false;1;1;;;;0;
```

Second File:

```
2019-10-29 16:13:11;;18;0;;3;false;false;true;
```

Now I have multiple rows like those, and I'd like to print them on different files based on their first value.

I managed to create a `class` which might represent each row:

```
class Value {
    public DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    public decimal cod = 0;
    public decimal quantity = 0;
    public decimal price = 0;
    //Other irrelevant fields
}
```

And I also tried to develop a `method` to write a single Value on given File:

```
private static void WriteValue(Value content, string folder, string fileName) {
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(folder, fileName), true, Encoding.ASCII)) {
        writer.Write(content.dataora.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        writer.Write("0000");
        writer.Write("I");
        writer.Write("C");
        writer.Write(content.codpro.ToString().PadLeft(14, '0'));
        writer.Write(Convert.ToInt64(content.qta * 100).ToString().PadLeft(8, '0'));
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

And a Method to write Values them into files

```
static void WriteValues(List<Value> fileContent) {
        //Once I got all Values of File in a List of Values, I try to write them in files
    }
    if(fileContent.Count > 0) {
        foreach(Value riga in fileContent) {
            //Temp Dates, used to compare previous Date in order to know if I have to write Value in new File or it can be written on same File

            string dataTemp = riga.dataora.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string lastData = string.Empty;
            string FileName = "ordinivoa_999999." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssfff");
            //If lastData is Empty we are writing first value
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastData)) {
                WriteValue(riga, toLinfaFolder, FileName);
                lastData = dataTemp;
            }
            //Else if lastData is equal as last managed date we write on same file
            else if (lastData == dataTemp) {
                WriteValue(riga, toLinfaFolder, FileName);
            }
            else {
               //Else current date of Value is new, so we write it in another file
                string newFileName = "ordinivoa_999999." + DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1).ToString("yyMMddHHmmssfff");
                WriteValue(riga, toLinfaFolder, newFileName);
                lastData = dataTemp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My issue is method above has strange behavior, writes first equal dates on a single file, which is good, but writes all other values in a single file, even if we have different dates.

How to make sure each value gets printed on in a single file only if has same date value?

Comment: What is the delimiter here? Seems like you have both `;;` and `;`, and even a `;;;` at one point.

Comment: Delimiter is ; If you see ;; it means there's an empty value in the middle

Comment: Please debug your code, you are initialize lastData inside loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path declaring a class, but you're also doing a whole bunch of unnecessary stuff. Using `LINQ` this can be simplified by a great deal.

First I define a class, and since all you want to do is write each record, I would use a `DateTime` field, and a `string` field for the entire raw record.

```
class MyRecordOfSomeType
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string RawData { get; set; }
}
```

The `DateTime` filed is so that it'll come in handy when you're doing `LINQ`.

Now we iterate through your data, split using `;`, then create your class instance list.

```
var data = new List<string>()
{
    "2019-10-28 16:14:14;;15.5;0;;3;false;false;0;111;123;;;10;false;1;2.5;;;;0;",
    "2019-10-28 16:13:11;;18;0;;1;false;false;222;333;123;;;10;false;1;1;;;;0;G",
    "2019-10-29 16:13:11;;18;0;;3;false;false;true;"
};

var records = new List<MyRecordOfSomeType>();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    var parts = item.Split(';');
    DateTime.TryParse(parts[0], out DateTime result);
    var rec = new MyRecordOfSomeType() { Date = result, RawData = item };
    records.Add(rec);
}
```

Then we group by date. Note that it's important to group by the `Date` component of the `DateTime` structure, otherwise it will consider the `Time` component as well and you'll have more files than you need.

```
var groups = records.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date);
```

Finally, iterate your groups, and write contents of each group to a new file.

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var fileName = string.Format("ordinivoa_999999_{0}.csv", group.Key.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssfff"));
    File.WriteAllLines(fileName, group.Select(x => x.RawData));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It almost works well, and I say almost because if first 2 values of csv file have same date they get written on 2 different files. All other values get correctly written on single files.

Comment: Please show a sample input. It shouldnt do what you say it does.

Comment: `DateTime` stores values in units of one ten-millionth of a second (ticks). Two dates looking equal might still be different. So you might have to create the filename first and to group by filename. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can group equal dates easily with a LINQ query

```
private static void WriteValues(List<Value> fileContent)
{
    var dateGroups = fileContent
        .GroupBy(v => $"ordinivoa_999999.{v.date:yyMMddHHmmssfff}");
    foreach (var group in dateGroups) {
        string path = Path.Combine(toLinfaFolder, group.Key);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true, Encoding.ASCII)) {
            foreach (Value item in group) {
                //TODO: write item to file
                writer.WriteLine(...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since a `DateTime` stores values in units of one ten-millionth of a second, two dates looking equal once formatted, might still be different. So I suggest grouping on the filename to avoid this effect. I used [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to create and format the file name.

Don't open and close the file for each text line.

At the top of your code file you need a

```
using System.Linq;
```